# How to programmatically receive event notifications from Google Calendar API

Tags: angular, express, socket.io, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a notification broadcasting system for events on Google Calendar. So far, I've developed a socket server in Express that is able to connect to my Angular 2 service worker on the front end, and successfully send and receive data in real time. Now all I have to do is connect my backend in a similar real time fashion to Google Calendar, so I can receive notifications of upcoming events.

The only possible way of doing this that I've seen so far is to check for new events and reminders on an interval, but that will rack up way too many requests on my quota. I was hoping to find a way to capture Google Calendar notifications like we receive on phones or SMS. I've looked at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch), and it's similar to what I want, but instead of watching for changes I'd like to watch for existing events as well.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Check the [Making watch requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests) where you can check if a resource, like events in a calendar, has change. This is what's supported by Calendar API at the moment as per the docs.

Comment: That's what I've linked. But I'm trying to watch for unchanged events as well